# Django Haystack with multiple databases

Tags: multiple-databases, django-haystack

Django recently added support for using multiple databases and "database routing". Does Haystack deal intelligently (or at all) with multiple databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a multi database configuration on production with django-haystack and whoosh and so far I didn't have any problems. Because haystack uses models as any application does every query passes through the  router.